# Excel: Unique with Filter formula for Blank and " " cells still returns an empty value from list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to use this formula to get the unique dates from my dataset. I've checked the table from it's dropdown header and it shows no (Blanks). I also don't see any empty cells, but I still get an empty value as the first cell returned from my formula array.

This is the formula I am using:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER('Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648, 'Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648<>"", 'Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648<>" "))`

This pulls in all the data correctly with the exception of the blank cell at the top.

Any help would be appreciated because I'm not sure where to look at this point and the dataset is 1000+ records.

Comment: Without seeing your data, or a sample data set that reproduces your problem, it is unlikely anyone will be able to assist you. If you add data that can be used to reproduce your problem, be sure to add it as **text** which can be copy/pasted, and not as a picture which cannot.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the FILTER function is as follows:

```
=FILTER(array, include, [if_empty])
```

It appears as though you have incorrectly attempted to write a second *include* condition in the *[if_empty]* parameter. Multiple conditions using AND logic should be multiplied together in the *include* parameter, and the optional *[if_empty]* parameter can either be omitted, or you could use something like "No records found" or "None". The correct formula structure would be as follows:

```
=FILTER('Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648, ('Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648<>"")*('Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648<>" "), "None")
```

However, since the most likely culprit in this case is one or more cells that contain a single space (" "), you could simplify the conditions with the TRIM function as follows:

```
=FILTER('Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648, TRIM('Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648)<>"", "None")
```

So the final formula with the UNIQUE function would be:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648, TRIM('Cleaning Sheet'!H2:H8648)<>"", "None"))
```

Comment: YEP! This fixed it. Thank you for the great explanation and help!